# Finding the cdf of a distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Two people wish to explore Asia, where both tourists have a lifetime that is exponentially distributed with mean $\theta$. $T$ is the length of time that Asia is being explored by at least one of the tourists.

How do I find the cdf of the distribution given the following:
1) Both tourists leave the hotel at time $t = 0$, where their lifetimes are independently distributed.
2) The second tourist leaves the hotel on the event of the first tourist becoming sick.

Comment: Let $X$ and $Y$ be the lifetimes. For the first problem, you want the cdf of $\max(X,Y)$. For the second problem, you want the cdf of $X+Y$. We assume that both technical problems are of a type familiar to you.

Comment: I am familiar with max(X,Y) but not with X+Y. Could you give a few hints as to how to find the cdf for X+Y. All I have is P(T<t)=P(X+Y<t).

Comment: You can get the density of the sum using a convolution Or else first  find the cdf of $W=X+Y$. This is $\int_{x=0}^\infty \int_{y=0}^{w-x}\lambda^2e^{-\lambda x}e^{-\lambda y}\.dy\,dx$. Then differentiate. Or look up Gamma distribution.

Answer (score 1):

The more difficult part of the problem is translating the "words" into technical language.

For 1), let $X$ be the lifetime of Tourist A, and $Y$ the lifetime of Tourist B. Exploration continues until both die. If $U$ is the length of time that exploration continues, then $U=\max(X,Y)$.

The probability that $U\le u$ is the probability both are dead by time $U$. The density function of $X$ is $\frac{1}{\theta}e^{-x/\theta}$ (for $\theta\gt 0$). It follows that the probability A is dead by time $u$ is $\int \frac{1}{\theta}e^{-x/\theta}\,dx$. This is $1-e^{-u/theta}$ (for $u\gt 0$). We get the same expression for $\Pr(Y\le u)$. Thus by independence
$$F_U(u)=(1-e^{-u/\theta})^2$$
for $u\gt 0$, and $F_U(u)=0$ elsewhere.

2) suppose that Tourist A leaves first. Then exploration time $V$ is given by $V=X+Y$. To find $\Pr(V\le v)$ for $v\gt 0$, we integrate the joint density  function over the part of the first quadrant that is below the line $x+y=v$. Thus for positive $v$ we have
$$F_V(v)=\int_{x=0}^v \left(\int_{y=0}^{v-x}\frac{1}{\theta^2}e^{-x/\theta}e^{-y/\theta}\,dy\right)\,dx.$$

The integration is straightforward. For generalizations, please see the *gamma* distribution, or more specifically the *Erlang* distribution.